# Angular show div based on URL parameter

Tags: html, angularjs, if-statement

Is there a way I can display content based on a URL parameter being present, in Angular?

For example, `myfile.php?id=123`

```
<div ng-if="window.location.search.id != ''">
    Show content
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using `ui-router` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of your controller/directive you can inject [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) and use it to check for query params

```
 angular
    .module('locationExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', 
     ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
         $scope.search = $location.search();
     }]);


<div ng-if="$scope.search.id != ''">
    Show content
</div>
```